# Is a child iframe absolutely safe for third-party code execution?

Tags: security, iframe, sandbox, postmessage, browser-security

I'm working on a site that receives third-party untrusted Javascript as a string, and needs to `eval()` it. The site has sensitive cookies and localStorage that the untrusted code cannot have access to.

To solve this, I created a child `iframe` to another page in the same domain, with `allow-scripts` as the only sandbox attribute:

`<iframe src="..." sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>`

The child `iframe` has a list of preset methods it can execute based on expected payload from the parent using `window.postMessage`. The child receives the parent payload including the untrusted code to be executed, `eval()`s it and returns the response as a string to the parent via `window.postMessage`.

I've tested and verified the child `iframe` can't access the parent cookies or localStorage.

AFAIK this is safe, but I would like to know from someone experienced in the area.

Comment: `returns the response as a string to the parent via window.postMessage` - at very least, the untrusted code can return you wrong response via this. This however would imply knowledge about your setup and a direct attack. Other than that, it could be exploiting browser vulnerabilities.